# May I know how to make 5 column and 4 column in the same table have the same width?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

May I know how to make these rows have the same width? I tried colspan and percentage of width, but seems not work well when col number equals 5.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Middle Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr >
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b/td> 
    <td>c</td> 
    <td>d</td>       
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 25%">Street address</th>
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 25%">City</th>
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 25%">State</th>
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 25%">Zip</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 25%">f</td>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 25%">g</td> 
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 25%">h</td> 
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 25%">i</td>       
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: That's not how `colspan` works. You have 5 columns TOTAL, and you're telling each column with `colspan="3"` to extend across 3 columns *each*.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it means like col-md-3...haha But how kan I make the first row of th and td to be five column and the second th and td to be 4 column and they all have the same whole width?

Comment: You seem to be conflating `colspan` (an attribute of the table data cell element) with Bootstraps Grid class structure.  These two things are very different.